# XmlSeeAlso and XmlRootElement names?

Tags: jaxb

In the reference JAXB implementation is there anyway to get XmlSeeAlso to use the name= value from XmlRootElement?

The effect I want is for the type attribute to use the name= value rather than actual class name from XmlSeeAlso.

Is this possible is some other JAXB implementation?

Small example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="some_item")
public class SomeItem{...}

@XmlSeeAlso({SomeItem.class})
public class Resource {...}

XML:
<resource xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="some_item">
...
</resource>
```

Possible without a lot of effort?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**About `@XmlSeeAlso`**

The purpose of the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation is just to let your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation know that when it is processing the metadata for `Resource` that it should also process the metadata for the `SomeItem` class.  Some people mistakenly believe that it is related to mapping inheritance since that is the use case it is most often used with.  Since the subclasses of a class can not be determined using Java reflection, `@XmlSeeAlso` is used to let the JAXB implementation know that mappings for the subclasses should also be created.

---

Below is an example of how you could support your use case:

**Resource**

The complex type name corresponding to a Java class is supplied via the `@XmlType` annotation.

```java
package forum12288631;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name="some_item")
public class Resource {

}
```

**Demo**

The root element name can come from the `@XmlRootElement` annotation or can be supplied via an instance of `JAXBElement`.  We will create an instance of `JAXBElement` and indicate that it is holding onto an instance of `Object`.  When marshalled this will for the `xsi:type` attribute to be included in the output.

```java
package forum12288631;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Resource.class);

        Resource resource = new Resource();
        JAXBElement<Object> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Object>(QName.valueOf("resource"), Object.class, resource);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

The resulting XML has the root element supplied by the `JAXBElement` and the value of the `xsi:type` attribute comes from the `@XmlType` annotation on `Resource`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resource xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="some_item"/>
```